# Need clarification about HashSet and duplicates in Java

Tags: java, duplicates, hashset

I need some clarification about what java considers as duplicate.

Consider the following code:

```
public class Fruit {

    private String name;
    private int juice;

    public Fruit(String name, int j) {
        this.name=name;
        this.juice=j;
    }

    //some more code here

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object fruit) {
        return (((Fruit)fruit).name.equals(this.name));
    }
}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Fruit a=new Fruit("Apple", 25);
        Fruit b=new Fruit("Apple", 22);

        HashSet<Fruit> hs=new HashSet<Fruit>();

        hs.add(a);
        hs.add(b);

        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
        System.out.println(hs.size());

    }
}
```

I created a Fruit class in wich I overriden equals(), so that two objects are considered equals if their name is equal.
Then, I added two Fruit objects (with the same name) to a HashSet.

Now, HashSet is supposed to prevent an attempt to add two objects that are equal.
Although, the output to the above code is:

true
2

so in one hand, Java considers these two objects (a and b) as equals, and on the other hand - HashSet doesn't consider these two as equals.
So what am I missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd pay attention what `HashSet` means. Why it has "hash" part :)

Comment: Thank you all for the answers.
I'll override the HashCode().
One more question though:
What if I'll use other data stracture that doesn't allow duplicates, and doesn't use hash, like, for example, TreeSet?

Comment: If you use `TreeSet` you either have to pass `Comparator` object that knows how to compare fruits or make `Fruit` implement `Comparable`, so it also requires extra work.

Comment: I don't know any `Set` implementation from standard JDK that uses only `equals` method.

Answer (score 4):

> HashSet doesn't consider these two as equals. So what am I missing
>   here?

You missed to override `hashCode` at `Fruit` class.

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
 return 31 * this.name.hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is `equals()` it is a duplicate otherwise it is not. If you want to make sure it does what you want override the `equals()` method.

You also have to overrdie the `hashCode` method since `HashSet` uses a `HashMap` internally. If you use a tool like Eclipse you can easily generate both using it.

Answer (score 0):

It is issue in your `hashCode()` method. you have to override both `equals()` and `hashCode()` method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your implementation of `equals` is wrong. You cast the parameter to `Fruit` without checking first if it actually is an instance of `Fruit`.

Second, when overriding `equals` you *must* override `hashCode` as well. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()

Answer (score 0):

HashSet and HashMap use two things to check for equality.

First it checks the HashCode for the two objects using getHashCode().

If and only if the HashCode matches it then checks for equality using the equals() method.

If equals returns true then the objects are considered to be the same.

Whenever you implement equals in a method you must also implement HashCode and there is a contract you need to follow about the behavior of the two methods. If you don't things like HashMap, HashSet, etc all have undefined and incorrect behavior.

You can see a detailed explanation here: http://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/java-equals-and-hashcode-contract/

Netbeans (and most other IDEs) are able to automatically generate equals and hash code methods for you. Just go to source->insert code->equals and hash code

You can then select what fields you want included and it will generate both methods for you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hashset and HashMap internally calls two method to check the equality.

first it checks for the HashCode for the if object is already in the bucket it will check for the equality using equals method.

In your case you have overridden the equals method but forget to override the Hashcode.

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
 return "Hash"+ this.name.hashCode();
}
```

This will give you correct results.